# What is the difference between inventory_source_item and inventory_stock_x?

Tags: magento2, inventory, quantity

With Magento's new multi-source inventory system, various new tables have been introduced into the database.

*inventory_source_item* contains the machine name of the source, SKU, quantity, and the status.

*inventory_stock_x* is a table that exists for each source, containing the SKU, quantity, and if it's salable.

Why does the second table exist, when the first could store all of that information?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*inventory_source_item*

Contains inventory levels for each source. A source is a physical location (like a warehouse).

*inventory_stock_x*

Contains aggregated levels for each stock. A stock can consists of one or many sources.

For example, you can have 3 warehouses (sources) in GB and one stock called "Great Britain" which would sum up all your warehouses in the inventory_stock_x table.

Comment: Thanks, Olivier. I think I knew that in the back of my mind, but after trying to understand the abstracted DB tables I lost sight of the big picture.

Comment: from where I can disable inventory_source_item zero entry.

Comment: @YoYoRoshan what do you mean by "disable"? If you mean to delete, well this can be done by a simple SQL. If you mean to disable its usage by Magento, you will need to disable the "Inventory" module or write a plugin to disable its usage and overwrite it with what you want.

Comment: @Olivier Thanks for the quick reply, I mean to remove all zero entries from inventory_source_item without SQL.